# Custom MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL is not used

Tags: php, email, logging, laravel-5.8

I encountered an issue with the mail system of laravel 5.8. As the documentation says, [Mail & Local Development](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mail#mail-and-local-development) one can change the way of sending emails to let it write them to a log-file.

Therefor, the `.env` as well as the `config/mail.php`-file have options for that.
So, I added (the key was not here originally) a `MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL`-key to my `.env`-file with the value "mail" and changed the value of the key `MAIL_DRIVER` to "log".

Obviously, I added a new channel to the `config/logging.php`:

```php
[...]
'mail' => [
            'driver' => 'single',
            'path' => storage_path('logs/mail-'.php_sapi_name().'.log'),
            'level' => 'info',
        ],
[...]
```

What ever I tried, the mail was never written to the seperate log-file. I testet the channel with a normal log-statement without any problem.
I switched from `MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL="mail"` to `MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL=mail` added a default value to the section of the `config/mail.php`:

```php
[before]
'log_channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),

[after]
'log_channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL', 'mail'),
```

not getting the width of a hair near to the log entry.

Only with the absolute basic configuration it actually writes the mail to the log but with this solution into the wrong log file.

Does anyone have an idea? It looks pretty strange to me.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6):

I found out why the logging was not working:
one have to change the `level`-propertiy to "debug".

After that, everything works fine.

See https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/custom-mail-log-channel-breaks-mail-driverlog?page=1#reply=523111

for the original hint for this issue.

May that can helkp someone :)

Have a nice day.